# How to get custom meta key and echo into class

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

This should be a simple thing, however I am at a loss at calling on this meta information. I want to apply custom css to posts marked as featured, specifically I want a css stamp on the corner. I have that part good, but I can't apply the class.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-item-metabox/

I tried this plug in, and it works well. I am able to pull a page with all of the articles I have set us featured but I can't for the life of me figure out how to pull the information to echo it as a class.

I've tried lots of things, this is the closest I've come to success I think:

```
<div class="featured"><?php echo get_post_custom_keys($post_id, '_featured'); ?></div>
```

Here I'm trying to just echo the contents so I can see what it is outputting, makes it easier to troubleshoot.

This seems like something that is basic but I'm at a loss. How should I call the custom meta key?

Comment: are you doing this within the wordpress loop?

Comment: I placed that div inside of the content.php that is being pulled by the loop.

Comment: @Marty yes this is within the loop

Answer (score 0):

You  should try with get_post_meta()
(http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

```
$all_meta = get_post_meta($post_id)
//dump($all_meta)
```

and check if your post has featured value.

Comment: I will try this later today.